# Discord bot to see which servers the logged in user is on

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, ejs

I'm trying to make a Discord server list, but I have no idea how to see which servers the users are on.
disboard.org
i will give an example
sample:
[image]

If you found the Discord server list infrastructure from somewhere or if you have a link to the infrastructure, can you send it to me?

Answer (score 2):

Discord's [OAuth2 API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2) contains the `guilds` scope, allowing an application to access an authorized user's guilds. After authenticating with OAuth2, you can [GET `/users/@me/guilds`](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user-guilds) to retrieve a list of guilds that the user is in. This returns a partial guild object containing the following data:

```
{
  "id": string,
  "name": string,
  "icon": string,
  "owner": boolean,
  "permissions": string,
  "features": Array<string>
}
```

Comment: How can I filter out servers where the person only has administrative privileges. I'm also wondering how can I get the ID of the server selected by the user?

Comment: @Emin All of that information is contained in the returned guild object. I edited my answer with more information; you can see an example of the returned object on the documentation page for the endpoint that I linked.

Comment: I couldn't, can you send me a code sample?

Comment: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/862799737778339840/879059322192142436/Ekran_Alnts.JPG This is how I did it, the bot responds as follows and I gave the bot permission according to my servers: https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/862799737778339840/879059349190881300/Eaakran_Alnts.JPG

Comment: Did you use the OAuth 2 API and authorize the user with the `guilds` scope? Keep in mind that that is different from the `bot` scope, which you use to add a bot to a guild.

Comment: what do you suggest i do?